# Upgrade CentOS 5.x to CentOS 6.x - tips and techniques

Tags: redhat, centos5, rhel5, centos6, rhel6

Now that CentOS 6.0 is making its way to the various mirror sites, I wanted to solicit opinions on the upgrade process. In working with the commercial RedHat 5.6 and 6.x distributions for the past few months, I've been relying on a fresh install instead of an in-place upgrade for my test systems.

Since the real CentOS 6 release is here, is anyone planning on performing the migration in-place? Are there any situations where it makes sense? If so, what are the pitfalls of an in-place update?

Comment: Do you mean 5.6? I don't find reference to 6.X anywhere on the main CentOS site

Comment: Nevermind, I found it... boy you really like bleeding edge eh? Have fun :)

Comment: I've been using RHEL6 in a limited capacity for months, then Scientific Linux 6, after resigning myself to the fact that CentOS 6 was just not going to happen... This morning, I noticed my local mirror was downloading quite a bit and discovered that 6.0 was finally released. But the one issue that hasn't been fully-addressed is the recommended migration path.

Comment: If you are running SL6, why switch back to Centos?

Comment: Just as a test-bed. I only started working with SL6 a week ago since I have a large number of systems that may need to be moved from RHEL/CentOS 5.6 to 6.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **We recommend everyone run through a reinstall** rather than attempt an 
>   inplace upgrade from CentOS-4 or CentOS-5!

Source: http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2011-July/017645.html

You can run this upgrade centos6 just by using `yum upgrade --enablerepo=centosplus`.

Do not forget: each system running centos is individual (!). I recommend you to test this upgrade on a virtual machine before upgrading (i did so!). Of course, this process may takes some hours. I've upgraded several internal systems virtually today and monitoring them right now. regards, msec.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may be possible to do such update with *Yum* and some manual tinkering, the only **supported** and **recommended** way to update from *CentOS 5.x* to *CentOS 6* is a clean re-install.

Comment: I don't think this answers his question.

Comment: Not an answer to the question.