# Upgrading Live CentOS / cPanel Servers

Tags: centos, upgrade

Can you upgrade cPanel/WHM servers with CentOS 4.9 and 5.8 up to CentOS 6.x?

Answer (score 2):

In-place upgrades are a difficult process. You will probably want to rebuild onto new servers and migrate your data. That gives you a test platform and a fallback point in case you application needs tweaking on the new OS.

In-place upgrades are no longer *supported*.

See:
 [Upgrade CentOS 5.x to CentOS 6.x - tips and techniques](https://serverfault.com/questions/288792/upgrade-centos-5-x-to-centos-6-x-tips-and-techniques) 
and
 [Why is it so difficult to upgrade between major versions of Red Hat and CentOS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449048/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-upgrade-between-major-versions-of-red-hat-and-centos)

Answer (score -2):

No, upgrading between major centos releases is not supported and requires a reinstall.